# test not recognized in dbt

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I have written a generic test in dbt: is_postive.sql

```
{% test is_postive(model, column_name) %}

select 
    {{ column_name }}
from {{ model }} 
where {{ column_name }} < 0

{% endtest %}
```

This test is located in the tests/generic folder in my dbt project. The dbt project yaml file sets the tests location to this folder `test-paths: ["tests"]`

I am trying to reference this test in a yaml file for a model:

```
models:
  - name: fct__monthly_revenue
    tests:
      - unique:
          column_name: "id || '-' || date"
    config:
      schema: analytics
    columns: 
      - name: revenue
        tests:
          - is_positive:
              severity: warn
```

however, when I try to build the model I get this error:

```
Compilation Error in test is_positive_fct__monthly_revenue_revenue (models/analytics/fpaa/fpaa_revenue.yml)
  'test_is_positive' is undefined. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".
```

Some things I have tried already:

- changing the file name to test_is_positive.sql
- originally had the test directly in the test folder instead of the generic sub-folder

And yes I do know that I could use the accepted range from dbt_utils but I'd like to build more custom generic tests and so I'm trying to get a relatively simple one to work first

Comment: I think maybe the file needs to be test_is_positive.sql ?

Comment: had a similar thought and tried that already. same result

Comment: Can you share how you tried? I think the above comment is right; the file name should be `test_is_positive.sql` and the test should be `is_positive` and the file should be in `tests/generic` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ugh, sorry turns out it was a typo in my test sql file:

`{% test is_postive(model, column_name) %}` should have been `{% test is_positive(model, column_name) %}`

Thanks Chiến Lê and Aleix CC for helping me notice that. Not marking those answers as correct since dbt is agnostic as to whether I call the file `is_positive.sql` or `test_is_positive.sql`, and whether I have `config:` prior to `severity:`

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine, except for the fact that when you define a `severity`, you need to also add `config:` on the YAML.

Try with the following:

```yaml
models:
  - name: fct__monthly_revenue
    tests:
      - unique:
          column_name: "id || '-' || date"
    config:
      schema: analytics
    columns: 
      - name: revenue
        tests:
          - is_positive:
              config:
                severity: warn
```

Comment: I had it configured like that originally and it gives the same error

Comment: Then I would just make sure of what was mentioned by tconbeer and Chiến Lê in the comments above:
- file name should be `test_is_positive.sql`
- test should be called `is_positive`
- the file should be in `tests/generic` folder

Comment: I assumed the `generic` folder is a suggestion, but it appears to be mandatory